# How to use external EEPROM (25AA320A) with the AT89S52 microcontroller over SPI

Tags: microcontroller, eeprom, 8051

I am using the AT89S52-24PU as my MCU for a project where I need to read data from an EEPROM chip (in this case the 25AA320A serial EEPROM chip) over SPI. On the datasheet for the AT89S52 it says that Pin 1.7 or SCK is serial clock input, on the datasheet for the 25AA320A it says that the SCK pin is also the serial clock input. Therefore I cannot simply connect SCK to SCK and call it a day. How should I use this EEPROM chip with the AT89S52 over SPI then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really old chip. The AT89S52 acts as an SPI slave during programming. You need an SPI master, which the AT89S52 lacks as a hardware peripheral.

So you can "[bit-bang"](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3524.html) an SPI interface- SPI has no rigid timing requirements, you can go as slow as you want (and it will be slow compared to a hardware SPI) so long as you respect setup and hold times (which is easy enough). Just create the proper waveforms (/CS, MOSI, SCK) on relevant GPIO pins and read the MISO output of the SPI EEPROM using your program.